# How to use GMP library in case of nested makefiles in c++

Tags: gmp

I have a source code of a tool written in c++. The tool is compose of several modules that compiles perfectly using a set of nested makefiles. I wanted to add a certain feature to a specific module in that tool that requires using the gmplib library. However, it gives me this error:

```
### Module sdf - sdf3cost
Creating executable sdf3cost-sdf
/sdf3/build/work/Linux/lib/libsdf3-sdf.so: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/sdf3/build/work/Linux/lib/libsdf3-sdf.so: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init_set_ui'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [sdf3cost-sdf] Error 1
make[2]: *** [sdf3cost] Error 2
make[1]: *** [tools] Error 2
make: *** [sdf] Error 2
```

I think that I know the reason behind that error is related to the usage of -lgmp flag. However, I don't know where to add it in the makefiles since they are nested. Or maybe it is a different problem, I don't know. Can any body help me please?